# How to test rest endpoint which accepts java object which contain multipart formadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I'm stuck with unit testing of rest controller which has post method
which is accepting a RequestBody of java object which contains the multipart file.

various options I search for shows how to send a single file along with request or making them as part.

is there a way to test the whole object as single entity.

**Model class**

```
@Data
public class Person{
  private String name;
  private String age;
  private List<MultipartFile> images;
}
```

and the rest controller to handle the request is

**Rest Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1)
public class PersonRestController{

  @Autowired
  private IPersonService personService;

  @PostMapping("/save")
  public ResponseEntity<String> savePerson(@ModelAttribute Person person){
    String name = personService.savePerson(person);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(name,HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }

}
```

will be really helpful if anyone could help.

Comment: You can try referring below https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/. 
Basically you can seperate out the Person object and list of files, in the same endpoint

Comment: @DeepakJain thanks but I cannot separate these two parts, 
because this is a sample code while in my project multipart needs to be there with java object and not as a separate part